# Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1 Column 'contact_list_data.d_campaign_code' is invalid error

Tags: sql, group-by

```
SELECT d_campaign_code, d_campaign_name, COUNT(di_load_date)
FROM contact_list_data a with (nolock)
INNER JOIN contact_list b with (nolock)
  ON a.contact_list_id = b.id
INNER JOIN campaign c with (nolock)
  ON a.contact_list_id = c.contact_list_id
GROUP BY d_campaign_code, campaign_name;
```

--This is the code currently and produces the error Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 1, Column and cannot resolve. Please assist or provide guidance on how to resolve this.

I tried Grouping by various other columns but displays the same error message and output is not working. Please help

Comment: I would suggest to add alias to the columns d_campaign_code, d_campaign_name. Probably, it will look like   c.d_campaign_code, c.campaign_name

Comment: withou seeing all the tables, i could never guss where d_campaign_code even comes from

Comment: Thanks Sergey. Will attempt it and update once completed

Comment: It's good programming practice to _qualify_ all columns (at least when several tables are involved.) E.g. `a.contact_list_id` instead of just `contact_list_id`.

Comment: Thanks for the quick responses and feedback everyone :) I am attempting all avenues based on the answers for rectification of the query

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms